# Rcpp: Obvious error when using igraph functions

Tags: r, function, igraph, rcpp

I'm quite new to Rcpp. Sorry If I'm missing something obvious. 
but when I try to use an igraph function in Rcpp I face the following obvious error on the left: 
"Cannot initialize a Variable of type 'RCPP:Environment' (aka,'int') with an lvalue of type 'const char[15]' 
 
Here is the code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector insideOfCommEdgeIdsCpp(CharacterVector g, CharacterVector v) {
Environment igraph("package:igraph");
Function game_er = igraph["erdos.renyi.game"];
Function get_adjacency = igraph["get.adjacency"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few small errors in your file:

- declared as `NumericVector` but nothing is returned
- `Environment igraph` not set up correctly.

A corrected version is below. And it it worth repeating this: *Any R functions called from C++* are still R functions that run at the speed of R functions.

#### Corrected code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void insideOfCommEdgeIdsCpp(CharacterVector g, CharacterVector v) {
  Environment igraph = Environment("package:igraph");
  Function game_er = igraph["erdos.renyi.game"];
  Function get_adjacency = igraph["get.adjacency"];
}
```